# Restrict jQuery-QueryBuilder To Build Only In DNF

Tags: jquery, css, sass, query-builder

I am trying to use [jQuery-QueryBuilder](http://querybuilder.js.org/) for constructing rules in [DNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) form (a disjunction of conjunctive clauses). These rules are only one level deep - and enforce that any **inner query group** is joined by *AND*, and any rules **within these groups** are all joined by *OR*. Right now, jQuery-QueryBuilder is way to expressive for what I need - and I'm trying to force it to only allow the construction of DNF formatted queries.

This requires three things:

1. Queries can only have one group
2. Outermost queries are joined by OR
3. Innermost queries are joined by AND

I can enforce that rules are only one level deep by using the `allow_groups: 1` when constructing the query (this works great!). However, I can't find a way to make the condition differ between group levels.

I can set the available conditions by using the `conditions` option ([docs](http://querybuilder.js.org/#options)) - but this works universally. I want to be able to set something like

```
outer_conditions = ['OR']
inner_conditions = ['AND']
```

I've also tried hiding the buttons with CSS (definitely not my specialty). This is as close as I've gotten so far:

```
// Hide main "AND" conditional value
.rules-group-container .rules-group-header .btn-group.group-conditions {
  display: none;
}

// Hide groups "OR" conditional value
.rules-group-container .rules-group-body .rules-list .btn-group.group-conditions > .btn:last-child {
  display: none;
}
```

This works when only hiding the inner conditional option, but does not work when trying to hide both.

Here is a JS fiddle I've been playing around with that restricts the groups to 1, hides the inner OR option, but does not hide the outer one.

https://jsfiddle.net/qzq1mm5z/3/

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Channeled all my inner CSS-foo and figured this one out. Made it work using wildcard selectors and `:not`.

This css excludes the buttons I want and rounds them over nicely to hide the fact that some buttons from a group are gone.

```
// Hide the main group "AND" button
#builder-basic_group_0 > .rules-group-header .btn-primary:nth-child(1) {
  display: None;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

// Fix the radius of the remaining "OR" button sharp edge
#builder-basic_group_0 > .rules-group-header .btn-primary:nth-child(2) {
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}

// Hide all child groups "OR" button
[id^="builder-basic_group_"]:not(#builder-basic_group_0) > .rules-group-header .btn-primary:nth-child(2) {
  display: None;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

// Fix the radius of all remaining "OR" button sharp edges
[id^="builder-basic_group_"]:not(#builder-basic_group_0) > .rules-group-header .btn-primary:nth-child(1) {
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
```

Fixed JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qzq1mm5z/4/